# Где можно получить список городов России для приложения

Tags: android

как лучше реализовать? если со своей базой, то хотелось бы видеть базу в json формате. Имеется ввиду что есть ли какие нибудь api для этого или примеры реализации? Может у кого есть сама база json?

Comment: Вы бы хоть страну то укажите, а то штатный экстрасенс в отпуске и мы не понимаем города какой страны вам нужны...

Comment: Да необходимо вывести именно список городов России в listView ну или любой другой элемент списка. Интересует меня сама база городов, где ее брать. Ну или какие есть сторонние API используя которые можно получить этот список

Comment: Наверное вам нужно [это](https://github.com/asakasinsky/russia.json). Делайте дополнения, редактируя сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментариях к нему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем использовал Google Places Api, получилось лучше чем я думал.

Answer (score 3):

Есть такая штука, называется [КЛАДР](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%94%D0%A0) - классификатор адресов России. Там все адреса нормализованы, классифицированы и проч.

Есть [облако КЛАДР](https://kladr-api.ru/), которое умеет отвечать JSON'ами, [примеры здесь](https://kladr-api.ru/integration/)

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую [VK API](https://vk.com/dev/database.getCities) . Работает очень быстро и просто - без OAuth и токенов. Позволяет сделать автокомплит-селекторы адреса/города/региона/страны (ещё школ/вузов/факультетов правда не уверен что вам это нужно). Готовые реализации кода, работающего с VK API найти не сложно. К VK таки немного больше доверия чем к КЛАДР в плане высоких нагрузок.